# Profile Field Level Security missing in XML when retrieve profile changes from scratch org

Tags: profile, salesforcedx, xml, field-level-security, salesforcedx-cli

In our DX project we maintain 4 profiles (3 custom and the System Administrator profile). When a scratch org is created I can push the project and everything deploys correctly including the profiles and all of the previously configured field level security (FLS).

```
sfdx force:source:push -g -f -u SCRATCHORG
```

Here is the FLS configured on the profile before the push (as is in VC):

```
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Address</field> 
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.MobilePhone</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.AnnualRevenue</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Closed_Reason__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Description</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Lead.DoNotCall</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Email</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Lead.Fax</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Lead.HasOptedOutOfEmail</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Lead.HasOptedOutOfFax</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Industry</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Jigsaw</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Lead.LastTransferDate</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.LeadSource</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Lead.Lead_Age_in_Days__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.NumberOfEmployees</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Phone</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Rating</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Title</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Lead.Website</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Opportunity.ExpectedRevenue</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
```

If I make any change to the profile (even just modifying the profile's description) and pull the changes locally via Salesforce CLI all of the previously configured FLS for all fields is missing and I need to manually reinstate them before I commit to version control (I can see my intended changes on the profile but also the entire code block above is missing from the XML).

```
sfdx force:source:pull -u SCRATCHORG
```

Is this a known bug with DX or am I doing something incorrectly? All of our developers that are working on the same DX repo are experiencing the same issue and it is causing a lot of time wasted to manually reinstate this FLS on all profiles that are pulled in order to commit actual changes to VC.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it seems to have been introduced around the time you initially posted your question, I'm 100% sure it has worked properly before. Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but as of the latest sfdx update it seems to have been fixed...

Comment: I'm still noticing this issue. Using NPM installation and just updated today. If I `source:pull` I see all my Account custom FieldPermissions removed, I discard these changes and I `source:push` which appears to deploy successfully, but then I Edit/Save Admin profile with no changes in the scratch org and again `source:pull` only to again see my FieldPermissions removed :/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has been flagged as a Known Issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000nZCLQA2&title=sfdx-force-source-pull-loses-field-level-security

The only workarounds listed on the known issue report are:
Use Metadata API
OR 
Fix profile xml manually

Comment: This was marked as fixed in Spring '19 but we're still seeing the issue.